# How to refresh a Webview in Nativescript on Buttonclick

Tags: webview, nativescript

I want to refresh my webview when a button in the component is clicked.

I can't find a way to do so.

webview.components.ts code:

```
import {
    ...
} 
@BasePage()
@Component({
    selector: "ns-webview",
    templateUrl: "./webview.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./webview.component.css"],
})
export class WebviewComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild("webView", { static: false }) webView: ElementRef;

    private noData: boolean = false;
    private dataLoaded: boolean = false;
    private schwellwerteLoaded: boolean = false;
    public isLoading = true;
    public graphPeriod = 1440;

 oLangWebViewInterface;
    constructor(
        private uiService: UIService,
        private dataService: DataService,
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private injector: Injector
    ) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.isLoading = false;
        }, 1000);
        orientation.setOrientation("landscape");
        this.setupWebViewInterface();
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        console.log("destroy");
        orientation.enableRotation();
    }

    onSubmit(period: number){
        // let webView: WebView = this.webView.nativeElement;
        let graphData = new GraphdataWrapper();
        this.graphPeriod=1440;
        this.graphPeriod= this.graphPeriod + period
        console.log(this.graphPeriod)
        this.load(graphData);
        // this.webView.reload(); 
    }
...
}
```

this.webview.reload is not working for whatever reason.
I have no clue why this is the case.
If you have any idea im glad to hear it.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the reload() method of the WebView

In your HTML file you will have something like this

```
<Button text="Refresh" (tap)="refresh()"></Label>
<WebView (loaded)="onWebViewLoaded($event)" src="https://www.google.com" ></WebView>
```

And then in your js/ts file you'll have something like

```
onWebViewLoaded(webargs) {
    this.webview = webargs.object;
}

refresh() {
    this.webview.reload();
}
```

Comment: I tried to do this, but its not working for me
I edited the question and you can see my code there.